# Decrypting .plist file that was encrypted on device?

Tags: ios, encryption, ios7, plist

I am trying to diagnose a problem with an unsupported app.  This app has encrypted it's .plist file (which hopefully contains the information that I need.)  I have the file system of the device backed up and accessible but have not been able to gain access to this specific applications files.  Does anyone have any tips on how I can try to go about this?

(Just to be clear, I do understand the difference between a binary and an xml .plist file.  I suspect that this is a binary file that has been encrypted.)

Answer (score 0):

If the file is truly encrypted, you will not decrypt is without finding the key.

Going off the assumption that the file is not actually encrypted, you should try to find what format and encoding it is. Do a hex dump of the file and look at the first few characters. Many file tropes have specific signatures there to identify their format and encoding.

Comment: This was one of the first things that I did.  The header of the file is complete gibberish.  I have access to the keychain on the device and suspect this was used in the encryption.  Is there a trial/error process that I can use to attempt to decrypt the files with various keys that I have?  I understand brute-force or dictionary attacks are completely out.  I'll post a hex dump when I get back to the office later.